# Как сделать свой микроконтроллер?

Tags: arduino, микроконтроллеры

Давно хотел сделать свой микроконтроллер. Но не знаю как и с чего начать. Искал в интернете, но ничего не нашёл.

Если кто знает что, помогите. Я изучаю arduino. Уже собирал несколько схем. Подключал различные модули и т. д.

Comment: Для начала бы стоило выучить основы схемотехники. Может попробовать создать что-то на основе существующих микроконтроллеров, а не с нуля бросаться в огонь.

Comment: Я изучаю arduino. Уже собирал несколько схем. Подключал различные модули и т. д

Comment: Модули вы используете с библиотеками? А смотрели исходники библиотек? Там все намного сложнее, чем вам кажется. Особенно наладить работу всех компонентов вместе. Как минимум еще своя среда нужна будет, не говоря про микроконтроллер.

Comment: http://megaprocessor.com если с 0, или вот такой проект: magic-1.  Вот вам ссылка https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/2j5n9e/could_you_make_a_cpu_from_scratch/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделать собственный микроконтроллер не так сложно, как кажется. Но для отладки точно потребуется осциллограф.

Возьмите плату ПЛИС, например, производства [Terasic](http://www.terasic.com.tw/en/), и [изучайте Verilog и VHDL](http://www.fpga4fun.com/).

Возможно, Вам будет небезынтересно ознакомиться с [моими собственными статьями](https://sites.google.com/site/vanyambauseslinux/fpga) по этой теме.

Answer (score 1):

Именно микроконтроллер у вас навряд ли получится сделать, так как МК - это процессор + периферия. А что бы сделать процессор очень рекомендую почитать Харрис и Харрис "Цифровая схемотехника и архитектура компьютера". Есть в свободном доступе, например, http://easyelectronics.ru/files/Book/digital-design-and-computer-architecture-russian-translation.pdf
Книга отличная! Все дается с азов, а заканчивается она разработкой процессора с набором команд MIPS.

Comment: В чём сложность добавления пары GPIO? Вот уже и с периферией, 299 регистр добавил -- и вот уже SPI почти готов!

Answer (score 0):

Надо взять ассемблер AVR и реализовать все команды в виде машины состояний, а также регистры, указатель стека, память, регистры ввода-вывода (в адресах памяти), контроллер прерываний и переферию (в начале можно без этого).

Для написания и тестирования не нужны даже платы, вся отладка должна идти на симуляторе (ModelSim, QuestaSim), только так можно выявить и исправить все ошибки.

Писать нужно синтезируемые конструкции, т.е. прогонять проект через синтизатор. Тестирование должно заключаться в том, чтобы программа откомпилированная под AVR работала точно также как на микроконтроллере. HDL позволяет её загрузить из файла в память процессора.

Даже самый простой стандартный микроконтроллер займет достаточно много времени для реализации. Но можно следать и свое ALU на минимальное количество команд, тогда придется написать не большой свой компилятор для своего ассемблера или генератор команд в тестбенче.